# P4 login command throws a message like so- Too many trys to get lock /homedir/.p4tickets.lck. How do I resolve this?

Tags: authentication, perforce

Even before deleting, I am trying to do a P4 login and Perforce shows an error-

Enter password: 
Fatal client error; disconnecting!
Operation 'client-SetPassword' failed.
Too many trys to get lock /homedir/.p4tickets.lck. 
where homedir is my home dir on the server

Comment: Try deleting the `.lck` file that it's complaining about?

Comment: Hi Sam, When I try to delete with "rm", shell says no such file

Comment: Usually this is a permissions problem on the lockfile. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585556/perforce-api-p4api-net-p4exception-too-many-trys-to-get-lock-p4tickets-txt-l