# Perforce API (P4API.NET): P4Exception: Too many trys to get lock p4tickets.txt.lck

Tags: c#, asp.net, perforce, p4api.net

I wrote an .NET Web Application to make Perforce connection but keeps getting below error message. This issue only occurs when I publish into the server. When I run this application in the local machine, it works perfectly fine but in the server, it looks like it keeps failing when I try to login.

> [P4Exception: Fatal client error; disconnecting! Operation
>   'client-SetPassword' failed. Too many trys to get lock
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\p4tickets.txt.lck. ]
>
> Perforce.P4.P4Exception.Throw(String cmd, String[] args,
>   P4ClientErrorList errors, P4ClientInfoMessageList details) in
>   c:\tmp\104564385\P4.NET\r19.2\p4api.net\p4api.net\P4Exception.cs:393
>   Perforce.P4.P4Server.RunCommand(String cmd, UInt32 cmdId, Boolean
>   tagged, String[] args, Int32 argc) in
>   c:\tmp\104564385\P4.NET\r19.2\p4api.net\p4api.net\P4Server.cs:1106
>   Perforce.P4.P4Command.RunInt(StringList flags) in
>   c:\tmp\104564385\P4.NET\r19.2\p4api.net\p4api.net\P4Command.cs:503
>   Perforce.P4.P4CommandResult..ctor(P4Command cmd, StringList flags) in
>   c:\tmp\104564385\P4.NET\r19.2\p4api.net\p4api.net\P4CommandResult.cs:142
>   Perforce.P4.P4Command.Run(StringList flags) in
>   c:\tmp\104564385\P4.NET\r19.2\p4api.net\p4api.net\P4Command.cs:373
>   Perforce.P4.Connection.Login(String password, Boolean allHostTicket)
>   in
>   c:\tmp\104564385\P4.NET\r19.2\p4api.net\p4api.net\Connection.cs:1071

Here is my partial code for connect/login

```cs
    private void Connect(Connection con)
    {
        con.UserName = username;
        if (con.Client == null)
        {
            con.Client = new Client();
            con.Client.Name = "";
        }
        con.Connect(null);
        con.Login(password);
    }
```

I've been also trying to use P4.Option and store password inside here and pass it to con.Connect() as a parameter instead of using con.Login() but it had the same issue (only when I published to the server.)

Can someone please help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a permission issue on the server filesystem.  By default, login tickets go in `%USERPROFILE%/p4tickets`.  Your app is running as the `System` user, which doesn't have a normal `Users` directory, so instead it's trying to write its tickets to the system folder (which the app might not actually have permission to write to).

Typically I'd solve this by using `p4 login -p` to avoid the need for a tickets file on the actual filesystem.  The other potential fix would be to explicitly set the ticket file location to a path that you're sure will be writable.

Comment: Thanks Sam for the quick response. I get I can use `p4 login -p` instead to avoid storing p4tickets but how would you write the code to achieve this in Login function? It looks like I can pass Options as a parameter but can't implement -p here.

Comment: `-p` is here: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/T_Perforce_P4_LoginCmdFlags.htm

Comment: I am even encountering this with a domain account and load user profile enabled in IIS

Comment: @Samwise how did you fix this? what does your new code look like?

Comment: See the answer.  There are three different solutions suggested, only one of which requires modifying the code.